# Representations of Fundamental Group and Monodromy

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have two representations of the fundamental group and I am under the impression they are the same. Any help in seeing this would be great.

Preliminaries: Let $\phi: E \to M$ be a n-fold covering map and let F be the locally constant sheaf with values in $H_{0}(\phi^{-1}(x_{0}), C)$ which is naturally isomorphic to $C^{n}$.

Representation 1: Let $F_{x_{0}}$ be the stalk at $x_{0}$. For $k \in \pi_{1}(M, x_{0})$, k induces an automorphism $A_{k} \in Aut(F_{x_{0}}) \simeq Aut(C^{n)}$. (To see this, think of k as a map from the interval to M. Cover this compact space with finitely many intervals on which the the image of the interval under k is constant under the sheaf. Say the first two are [0, b), (a, b). Then we have $F_{x_{0}} \simeq F_{k([0, a)} \simeq F_{k(a)} \simeq F_{k(a, b)} \simeq F_{k(b)}$ where all the isomorphisms are induced by the inclusions of open sets. Continuing this process throughout the whole loop k we get the desired automorphism.)

Representation 2: Let $k \in \pi_{1}(M, x_{0})$ lift to a path starting at $y_{0}$. Define an action of k on fiber $\phi^{-1}(x_{0})$ by having k send $y_{0}$ to wherever this lift ends. This gives a permutation of $\phi^{-1}(x_{0})$. Mapping the k-element set $\phi^{-1}(x_{0})$ to the usual basis of $C^{n}$ means k gives an element $B_{k} \in Aut(C^n)$.

It occurs to me while writing this up that for there to be any hope these representations were the same the process of "Mapping the k-element set $\phi^{-1}(x_{0})$ to the usual basis of $C^{n}$" would have to be tightened up. However, I am under the impression both of these actions are the "monodromy action" and so the use of "the" makese me think they must give the same representation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're the same. This is just the claim that sending a set $X$ to the free vector space $\mathbb{C}[X]$ on that set is a functor. This would be much clearer if you never talked about $\mathbb{C}^n$ in this argument (which is a distraction because it hides functoriality), but only about the free vector space on some fiber.